# BusyBox v1.21.1 problem

Tags: 14.04, busybox

I have been using ubuntu 14.04. for about 5 years and there wasn't any problems until last week. I can not boot the system, I have typical initramfs problem. I have watched many youtube videos and I have read tons similar topics here about solving this popular problem but nothing worked for me, really nothing. I was trying all the "exit", "fsck /dev/sdaX" commands and also I couldn't boot Ubuntu from live USB stick. I'm not  advanced in Linux so I'm really hope that there will be someone willing to help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears that your root (system) partition does not exist, or at least the system cannot find it. What did you do to the system immediately before this happened? If you know anything about your UUIDs the ALERT! message may give you a clue.